# Soft question on the area of a parallelogram using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was reading this question:  [How do you find the area of a parallelogram with the vertices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966062/how-do-you-find-the-area-of-a-parallelogram-with-the-vertices)

$A_\text{parallelogram}= \left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}\right| = \left| \begin{pmatrix}4\\2\\0\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}9\\6\\0\end{pmatrix} \right| = \left|\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\6\end{pmatrix}  \right| = 6$

the part I dont understand is how is $(4,2,0) \times (9,6,0)= (0,0,6)$ whats the arithmetic behind the formula?

Comment: This is the cross product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: @CyclotomicField I thought that the cross product was only for $n \times n$

Comment: Nope it takes two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and produces another that is orthogonal to both of the original vectors. It's very specialized that way.

Comment: @CyclotomicField   excuse me for being niave but $9 \times 4 =36$ and $2 \times 6 = 12$. I dont care for the answer I just need the mechanics on how to calculate it properly

Comment: I can't make you click the link you have to do it yourself.

Comment: The cross product is not the pointwise product.

Comment: In this particular case, since both vectors are in '$\mathbb{R}^2$', you can compute the area of the paralleogram with $\det \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 9 \\ 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay that was very useful

Comment: if I could give you more points I would\

Comment: :-). Glad to be able to help!